# prepare SD card for headless operation

Tags: sd-card, headless

I'm trying to prepare an SD card for a Raspberry Pi 4 B which should boot up

1. without any interaction
2. without any desktop i.e. shell only
3. with network preconfigured

image being used: [2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img.xz](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2022-04-07/2022-04-04-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img.xz)

For the **preconfigured network** I'm doing this:

```
export PREFIX=/mount/point/to/sd/card/rootfs
echo ''                 | sudo tee -a ${PREFIX}/etc/dhcpcd.conf > /dev/null
echo 'interface eth0'           | sudo tee -a ${PREFIX}/etc/dhcpcd.conf > /dev/null
echo "static ip_address=${IPADDRESS}"       | sudo tee -a ${PREFIX}/etc/dhcpcd.conf > /dev/null
```

However, for the startup without an interaction / without a desktop I do not know what to change on the SD card. Do you have any hints?

I do not want to use `raspi-config`, I do want to prepare everything at SD preparation stage.

Thank you

Comment: Have you read the [new setup instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/)? Quite a few changes.

Comment: Have you tried running the Raspberry Pi Imager tool that does a lot of the stuff for you?  https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

Comment: "I do not want to use `raspi-config`, I do want to prepare everything at SD preparation stage." 

Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [Seamus](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/83790/seamus), for your [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137085/prepare-sd-card-for-headless-operation?noredirect=1#comment233448_137085), I indeed haven't read through it before. Those [setup instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/) did in fact help me:

- using userconf.txt did help me preventing the user creation dialog
- deleting `${PREFIX}/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf` did prevent autologin

Everyting works now as expected and I can mass-prepare my images.
Thank you all who answered!

Comment: Glad it helped... this has given me a thought  :)  I've got a *pre-prohibition* `bullseye-lite` image file... I wonder what it's worth now?  lol